# What is the syntax for " M_PI_4" and "M_PI_2" in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I know `M_PI` is now `CGFloat.pi` but am not sure what `M_PI_4` would be.  I tried `CGFloat.pi*4` but that wasn't correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift 3.1:
`M_PI_4` is now `.pi / 4`

Comment: Isn't it expensive to calculate it each time instead of using a const?